# How To Log number of Records in EF Select Command

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am use EF to get records by SELECT statement. for some performance issue I,m need to log Commands so that returned number of rows exeeds for example 1000. but I can not found any examples or documentation to do that.

I think could use IDbCommandInterceptor and implement CommandExecuted method to achive that. but not sure.

Are IDbCommandInterceptor is usable or should do it in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Searching Web and debug & trace & Investigate EF Source I realized that that's impossible by current Implementation.  IDbCommandInterceptor.CommandExecuted Interceptor called just after query on Database, that only we have DbDataReader, command, ... but not fetch record count.
to get fetched record count enumerate against DbDataReader should be done to can get row count. so I changed EF LazyEnumerator and after each call to MoveNext, increment local variable and when disposing LazyEnumerator we have fetched row number or materialized entity number

Comment: I guess that is not impossible since EFProf can collect that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Context Log property` as shown below.

**Note :** This is just an example. Change it as you wish.

```
 using (var context = new BlogContext()) 
   { 
    context.Database.Log = Console.Write; 

    var blog = context.Blogs.First(b => b.Title == "One Unicorn"); 
  }
```

Above will generate the following output:

```
SELECT TOP (1)
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
    [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title]
    FROM [dbo].[Blogs] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (N'One Unicorn' = [Extent1].[Title]) AND ([Extent1].[Title] IS NOT NULL)
-- Executing at 10/8/2013 10:55:41 AM -07:00
-- Completed in 4 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```

You can Customise `DatabaseLogFormatter` if you want.

***You can override below mentioned methods :***

> LogCommand – Override this to change how commands are logged before
>   they are executed. By default LogCommand calls LogParameter for each
>   parameter; you may choose to do the same in your override or handle
>   parameters differently instead.
>
> LogResult – Override this to change how the outcome from executing a
>   command is logged.
>
> LogParameter – Override this to change the formatting and content of
>   parameter logging.

Here is an example how to do that :

```
public class OneLineFormatter : DatabaseLogFormatter 
{ 
    public OneLineFormatter(DbContext context, Action<string> writeAction) 
        : base(context, writeAction) 
    { 
    } 

    public override void LogCommand<TResult>( 
        DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<TResult> interceptionContext) 
    { 
        Write(string.Format( 
            "Context '{0}' is executing command '{1}'{2}", 
            Context.GetType().Name, 
            command.CommandText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ""), 
            Environment.NewLine)); 
    } 

    public override void LogResult<TResult>( 
        DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<TResult> interceptionContext) 
    { 
    } 
}
```

**Reference :** [**Logging and Intercepting Database Operations**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx)

Comment: this log only show commandtext, .. but not fetched row number.

Comment: thanks. but where & how can I get fetched row number.

Comment: have you sorted out your issue or what ?

Comment: yes I am sorted problem, but I change EntityFramework source and use that version, the official EntityFramework version don;t have such facility.